# Why gradle files downloaded into the project?

Tags: java

For one of my Android projects, all gradle files including caches, deamon, JDKs, wrapper folder downloaded in my projects folder. what is wrong?[image]

Comment: show us `gradle.properties` also, make sure that you didn't override environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` which IIRC should points to `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I don't know why but somehow the Gradle address in the android studio setting was set to my projects folder! Changed and then removed these files manually.